# Why is my histogram implementation segfaulting even though it shouldn't because I'm looking for values inside bound?

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, memory, segmentation-fault

So, the histogram I implemented, basically takes a string as input, and divides it into words, and then the length of that word is used as the index, the output is an integer array. a[p]++, if strlen(s)==p basically. My code either prints one zero or doesn't work at all. Why?
The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define array_size(_S) 5000 //didn't want to edit code, this used to be a formula.

//an input function I coded when I was a beginner.
void input_str(char * str, int delimeter, int bound)
{
    int inpchar;
    register int incvar = 0;
    while (incvar < bound)
    {
        inpchar = getchar();
        if(inpchar == '\n' || inpchar == delimeter)
        {
            *(str+incvar) = '\0';
             return;
        }
        *(str+(incvar++))=inpchar;
    }
    *(str+incvar) ='\0';
}

//old code I used
int lenstr(char * str)
{
    register int varinc = 0;
    while( *(str + varinc) != '\0')
    {
        varinc++;
    }
    return varinc;
}

void xprintf(const char *s)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while ( *(s + counter) != '\0')
    {
        putchar(*(s + counter));
        counter++;
    }
}

void initialize(int **a, unsigned int len)
{
    int counter = 0;
        while(counter < len)
        {
            *(a + counter) = 0;
             counter++;
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    char inp_str[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    printf("Enter full string.\n");
    input_str(inp_str,-1,BUFFER_SIZE);
    int ncounter = 0;
    int ecounter = 0;
    int frequency_array[ array_size(inp_str)];
    intialize (frequency_array, array_size(inp_str));
    int real_length = lenstr(inp_str);
    while (ncounter <= real_length)
    {
        while(*(inp_str + (ncounter + ecounter)) != ' ' && *(inp_str +(ncounter + ecounter)) !='\0')
        {
            ecounter++;
        }
        frequency_array[ecounter]++;
        ncounter = ncounter + ecounter + 2;
        ecounter = 0;
    }
    ncounter = 0;
    while (ncounter < array_size(inp_str))
    {
        putchar(*(frequency_array + ncounter) + '0');
        ncounter++;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Right now, it just segfaults.

Comment: See compiler warnings for `intalize(frequency_array,array_size(inp_str));` which are `'int **' differs in levels of indirection from 'int [5000]'` and `different types for formal and actual parameter 1`

Comment: @Fe2O3 The instructions say I can only use getchar and putchar for input and output

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed it, still segfaulting

Comment: It takes an input string and returns a frequency array. The input is instantaneous.

Comment: Don't write things like `*(s+counter)`.  Just write `s[counter]`.  It's equivalent, and far more readable.  That's why this syntax exists.  Don't fight the language.  The posted code is littered with this.  Also, don't use a `while` loop when the loop clearly fits the pattern for a standard `for` loop.  Again, it just bloats your code and makes it harder to follow.

Comment: Please, don't be afraid of space button

Answer (score 0):

`intialize (frequency_array, array_size(inp_str));`

you misspellt initialize, so it gives an error due to that, write `initialize(frequency_array, array_size(inp_str));` to fix that error.

`void initialize(int **a, unsigned int len)`

Putting two asterisks ('*') means it is a pointer to a pointer, but from its use and implementation you intend it to work with regular arrays/pointers. So just change it to `void initialize(int *a, unsigned int len)`

Also, when this code compiles without errors, as it did for me after I fixed the issues I mentioned, it printed out a ridiculously huge string. This is because the `array_size(inp_str)` macro is always equal to 5000, and not the size of the array. An implementation for that array would be:

`#define array_size(s) (sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]))`

This would divide the total size (in terms of bytes) of an array and divide it by the size of a single element, thus giving you the size.

This should fix the segfault and help with other errors. Hopefully this helped!